# Space between @ and user name

Tags: discussion

Is there an easy way to let people know that if you put a space between the @ symbol and a user's name, they won't be alerted?

Comment: Direct them to this question?

Comment: Hehe. Fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you respond to them (by typing an @ symbol followed by their name), they'll receive an inbox notice. So perhaps something like,

> Hey, @newb: I wasn't notified of your last comment, because you put a space between the @ and my name. Next time, please omit the space - that way, I can read and respond to you  promptly. For more, [check the FAQ](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: There's a >99.999...% chance `@newb` probably won't notify them either.